# Collect multiple rows and store values in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, collections

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE
  type INV_TASK_GLOBAL is varray(10) of NUMBER(20,0);
  type STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL is varray(10) of NUMBER(20,0);

BEGIN
  SELECT T_INVESTIGATIONTASK.ID, T_STUDYCASE.ID 
     into INV_TASK_GLOBAL, STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL 

  FROM T_VALIDATIONCARRIER 
      left join T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT on T_VALIDATIONCARRIER.IA_ESTIMATIONOBJECT_ID = T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT.ID
      left join T_INVESTIGATIONTASK on T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT.INVESTIGATIONTASK_ID = T_INVESTIGATIONTASK.ID
      left join T_STUDYCASE on T_INVESTIGATIONTASK.STUDYCASE_ID = T_STUDYCASE.ID

  WHERE T_VALIDATIONCARRIER.ESTIMATIONOBJECT_ID = 940;

  dbms_output.Put_line('INVESTIGATIONTASK_ID: ' || INV_TASK_GLOBAL);
  dbms_output.Put_line('STUDYCASE_ID: ' || STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL);
END;
```

The compiler is telling me that the number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned. The fact is that I **want** those lines to be returned. To be specific: I would like to collect all the `T_INVESTIGATIONTASK.ID` and `T_STUDYCASE.ID` (one per each row which is captured by the `WHERE` clause), store them into the `INV_TASK_GLOBAL` and in `STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL` and then display all the values returned (separated maybe by a comma).
I may change the `WHERE` condition in the future but the maximum number of elements I expect to be returned for both variables is 10 anyway. 
I know that I am using the varray datatype in a wrong way: I need some sort of cycle and a list/array datatype to store all the returned values in the `INV_TASK_GLOBAL` and `STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL` variables and then print the array on screen. Do you have any idea of how to accomplish it?

Comment: This question seems similar to this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988636/how-to-populate-an-array-in-an-oracle-stored-procedure/3988988#3988988

Also this may help teach you how to use a vararray: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-jul/o42plsql-1653077.html

Comment: Take a look at the Oracle link above and try out BULK COLLECT INTO ....

Comment: By *"the number specified in exact fetch is less than the rows returned"* did you mean *"ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows"*? That doesn't sound like a compiler error though.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson yes, I think this means that I am returning more rows than what can be contained by the variable (that were declared in the beginning as ´INV_TASK_GLOBAL NUMBER(20,0)´. That's why I am trying to use varray to store all the data returned by the query. I am looking at the BULK COLLECT although.

Comment: OK. It's not a compiler error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests the following code solved my problem:

```
DECLARE
  type collection_id is table of NUMBER(20,0);

  INV_TASK_GLOBAL collection_id := collection_id(10);
  STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL collection_id := collection_id(10);

BEGIN
  SELECT T_INVESTIGATIONTASK.ID, T_STUDYCASE.ID 
    BULK COLLECT into INV_TASK_GLOBAL, STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL 
  FROM T_VALIDATIONCARRIER 
     left join T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT on T_VALIDATIONCARRIER.IA_ESTIMATIONOBJECT_ID = T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT.ID
     left join T_INVESTIGATIONTASK on T_ESTIMATIONOBJECT.INVESTIGATIONTASK_ID = T_INVESTIGATIONTASK.ID
     left join T_STUDYCASE on T_INVESTIGATIONTASK.STUDYCASE_ID = T_STUDYCASE.ID
  WHERE T_VALIDATIONCARRIER.ESTIMATIONOBJECT_ID = 940;

  FOR indx IN 1 .. INV_TASK_GLOBAL.COUNT
  LOOP
     dbms_output.Put_line('INVESTIGATIONTASK_ID: ' || INV_TASK_GLOBAL(indx));
  END LOOP;

  FOR indx IN 1 .. STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL.COUNT
  LOOP
      dbms_output.Put_line('STUDY_CASE_ID: ' || STUDY_CASE_GLOBAL(indx));
  END LOOP;
END;
```